# Foreign key receiving two primary keys from the same table - Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am having a problem trying to create a Composite Id that receives one foreign key from one table and another foreign key from another table, but this second foreign key contains two primary keys and this giving my a big headache to resolve. Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?

Here is my code:

Entity

```
public class GrupoArquivo
{
    public GrupoArquivo() {}

    public GrupoArquivo(ArquivoRetorno arquivoRetorno, GrupoModulo grupo, GrupoModulo modulo) : this()
    {
        Arquivo = arquivoRetorno;
        Grupo = grupo;
        Modulo = modulo;
    }

    public virtual ArquivoRetorno Arquivo { get; protected set; }
    public virtual GrupoModulo Grupo { get; protected set; }
    public virtual GrupoModulo Modulo { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var grupoArquivo = (obj as GrupoArquivo);

        if (grupoArquivo != null)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
                return true;

            var thisHash = GetHashCode();
            var otherHash = grupoArquivo.GetHashCode();

            return thisHash.Equals(otherHash);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Concat("{0}|{1}|{2}", Arquivo, Grupo, Modulo).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Mapping

```
 public class GrupoArquivoMap : ClassMap<GrupoArquivo>
{
    public GrupoArquivoMap()
    {
        Schema(Const.SCHEMA);
        Table(Const.TB_EMAIL_GRUPO_ARQUIVO);

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Arquivo, Const.ID_ARQUIVO)
            .KeyReference(x => x.Grupo, Const.ID_GRUPO)
            .KeyReference(x => x.Modulo, Const.ID_MODULO)
            ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it and it was quite "simple", I had to reference each table only once in the entity and in the mapping I defined the two collumns coming from the same table on the same "KeyReference".

Entity

```
    public GrupoArquivo() {}

    public GrupoArquivo(ArquivoRetorno arquivoRetorno, GrupoModulo grupoModulo) : this()
    {
        Arquivo = arquivoRetorno;
        GrupoModulo = grupoModulo;
    }

    public virtual ArquivoRetorno Arquivo { get; protected set; }
    public virtual GrupoModulo GrupoModulo { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var grupoArquivo = (obj as GrupoArquivo);

        if (grupoArquivo != null)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(obj, this))
                return true;

            var thisHash = GetHashCode();
            var otherHash = grupoArquivo.GetHashCode();

            return thisHash.Equals(otherHash);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return string.Concat("{0}|{1}|{2}", Arquivo, GrupoModulo).GetHashCode();
    }
```

Mapping

```
public class GrupoArquivoMap : ClassMap<GrupoArquivo> 
{
    public GrupoArquivoMap()
    {
        Schema(Const.SCHEMA);
        Table(Const.TB_EMAIL_GRUPO_ARQUIVO);

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.Arquivo, Const.ID_ARQUIVO)
            .KeyReference(x => x.GrupoModulo, Const.ID_GRUPO, Const.ID_MODULO)
            ;
    }
}
```